# Query to fetch from a column having multiple values and compare with another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to compare a Column A with Column B where

```
Column A      
  "joe" 

Column B 
  BAK_LOGIN:YBAK_SUB_ACCT:joeBAK_SRVID:BasicBAK_QUOTA_EXCEEDED:Y
```

So the second subfield `BAK_SUB_ACCT:joe` must be compared with `Column A`.

How do i do this?

Thanks&Regards,

Kumar

Comment: Don't store data like that is my advice. It will only cause you problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like operator

`WHERE columnB like '%BAK_SUB_ACCT:'||columnA||'%'`

Comment: I would make it: WHERE columnB like '%BAK_SUB_ACCT:'||columnA||'BAK%' OR columnB like '%BAK_SUB_ACCT:'||columnA to avoid false positive due to substrings matches